# CouchApp macro can't find file in _attachments directory

Tags: couchdb, couchapp

I'm trying to create a show function and use the `!json` macro to access some HTML in a file in the *_attachments* directory of a standard CouchApp.

However when I try and push the CouchApp, it says

> MacroError: Processing code: No file matching '_attachments.foo'

where *foo.html* is what I'm trying to access.

It can find the file if I move *foo.html* to the top of the directory structure, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Well I assume the !json macro can only find things that are actually on the _design document, not things that end up being attachments.